# Laravel Vapor CI/CD authentication issue

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, laravel-vapor

I am trying to automate a CI/CD pipeline, pushing commits from my git repo to AWS/Lambda using Vapor, the problem is, Vapor authentication is not mentioned anywhere within the documents except manually, API is supported via Web UI but is not mentioned under docs either ! vapor-cli help options were not much of a help either, anybody knows how to automate the login/authentication ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `VAPOR_API_TOKEN` environment variable to your CI build environment.

https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/deployments.html#deploying-from-ci